# Sharing profile and roles information between web applications

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security, roles

Q1 Book says that we can choose to share profile information between web application by having profile providers use the same *ApplicationName* value. But would it also be ok for applications to share roles, or would that represent a security risk?

Q2

If *ProfileManager.AutomaticSaveEnabled* is set to *True*, then when change is made to any profile data, the *ProfileModule* will update tables in a database accordingly. When dealing with properties containing simple types, *ProfileModule* checks *IsDirty*  to determine whether property has changed.

A) Assume *Profile.Name* already contains value “*Irene*”, when the program issues the following statement:

```
Profile.Name = "Irene";
```

Will *Name* property be marked as dirty even though same value has been assigned to it?

B) If *ProfileManager.AutomaticSaveEnabled* is set to *True* and if property containing complex type is set to read-only, then I assume *ProfileManager* will realize that and thus won’t try connect with database in order to save this property?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

1) If you're happy with a user having the same roles on both sites, then it's not a problem, and provides simplified management. If you want the users to have different roles on each site, then there's something to be said for seperating it out.

2) Can't say I've tried either scenario, sorry.